# Jquery Calender script into .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script on .aspx file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#<%=txtdateofjoin.ClientID %>').datepicker(
          {

              dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
          }

         );

    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        $('#<%=txtdateofjoin.ClientID %>').datepicker(
          {

              dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
          }

         );

    }
});
```

Its working and i tried to make this script as .js file

1) i have Created .js file
2) I dropped a Jquery plugins
3)

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.8.3.min.js" />


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#<%=txtdateofjoin.ClientID %>').datepicker(
          {

              dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
          }

         );

    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        $('#<%=txtdateofjoin.ClientID %>').datepicker(
          {

              dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
          }

         );

    }
});
```

named as CustomCalender.js

and I dropped CustomClender.js file to my .aspx  but this script not Working.

Why it doen't work? how to rectify it?

Comment: yes because you can only put javascript codes in a .js file

Comment: can you check in browser console for errors and post here if any?

Comment: I hit F12 on the Error tab there is no Error. and Clicked Warning Tab which Shows that "Empty string passed to getElementById()"

Comment: I got this Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%=txtdateofjoin.ClientID %>

Comment: Looks like you have put some server side aspx code in js file that is why it is not working. Please separate your server side and client side code and then you can move the js to an external file. Hope you got my point :)